# Dealing with approximate plataus in data?

Tags: javascript

I'm using js to analyze pulse data. I want to figure out how fast the users recover once day stop training. I run through the pulses an array like this to find min and max values:

```
var extrema = [];
//lägg in första värdet
extrema.push(run[0])
for (var i = 1; i < run.length - 1; ++i) {
    let previous = run[i-1],
        next     = run[i+1],
        current  = run[i]
    if(
        previous > current &&  next > current ||
        current > previous && current > next 
    ){
        extrema.push(run[i])
    }
}
extrema.push(run[length - 1])
console.log(extrema)
```

here is a sample of how the data might look, realworld has more granularity but this get's the gist of it:

```
[... 160, 150, 152, 151, 162, 173, 180, 191, 188, 190, 180, 170, 160, 150, 151, 149]
```

it should output

```
   [
      151, //the first value of the plateau
      190, //The last value before the recovery period(note that it's not neccesarily the biggest value
      150 // first value of the plateau, not the smallest
   ]
```

sometimes the peaks are on ~180, sometimes ~200

This sometimes generates local min and max values that are not interesting to me, I'm looking for recovery periods, where k < 0. So i'm interested in the last min value and the first max value.

My best idea is to loop through the min and max-values and see if they are relatively close to each other.

Is there any best practices for doing this?
What is this called?
Any libs I should know about?

Comment: please show the array

Comment: Please add input and desired output

Comment: added input for clarity, now i'll go have a run to gather some more data ^^

Comment: I would group values that are next to each other and that are in a range of ~5. And then you can analyze these groups.